# Pointwise convergence V.S. Uniform convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

[image]

My teaching assistant explained that for $f_k$, depicted like the above picture, $f_k$ pointwisely converges like the picture, but $f_k$ does not uniformly converge.

---

I could guess $f_k(x)=1-kx$.

Then, $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)=y\mbox{-axis}$.

---

How can I approach the case like the above?
Could someone make me understand the teaching assistant's picture?
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: The functions are not defined properly. Right now, if $x\neq 0$, then $f_{k}(x)\to -\infty$ as $k\to\infty$. You have to cap the functions to zero if the values are negative.

Comment: Could I ask about cap? What does it mean? And, teaching assistant drew only that picture without any explanation. The equation $f_k(x)=1-kx$ is just my supposition, so there are high probability that the function is wrong.

Comment: So you have to make the function zero if it gets negative values. So take for example $g_k = \max\{f_k,0\}$, where $f_k$ is as you wrote it. Then $f_k$ converges to the limit function that you want.

Comment: Ah-ha! you mean I have to make the function be bounded below as 0. Can I ask why $f_k$ can pointwisely converge but cannot uniformly converge?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. The reason is that $\sup|f_k(x)-f(x)|=1$ for all $k$. But it obviously converges point wise

Comment: If $f_k(x)=\max{1-kx, 0}$, then $\sup |f_k(x)-f(x)| = 1\ne 0$. So, $f_k(x)$ does not uniformly converge. But it pointwisely converges. Can you tell me f(x)=???? and why pointwisely converge?

Comment: $f$ is zero everywhere except $f(0)=1$. Try forming an argument and if you come to some specific problems I'll explain what went wrong. But try it yourself first.

Comment: Thank you. I finally got it!!! :) hahaha, I re-felt that the definition is the most important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the functions are $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}1-nx, &0 < x \leq \frac{1}{n} \\ 0, & x > \frac{1}{n} \end{cases}$$

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb R^+$. Then clearly, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x_0) =0$.

So, the pointwise limit is $f(x)=0$

However, the graphs of the functions $f_n(x)$ and their limit $f(x)$ don't get close for every $x$.

That is, whatever $f_n(x)$ you draw, that graph will still have points far away from the graph of $f(x)$.

For instance, take $n=10$. Draw the graph of $f_{10}(x)$. Is every point of that function close to the limit function $f(x)$? No.

For example, $f_{10} \left( \frac{1}{20} \right) = \frac 12$. However $f \left( \frac{1}{20} \right) =0$.

So, since $\frac{1}{2}$ and $0$ are "not close", the convergence is not uniform.

By the way, if you add $0$ to the domain of $f_n(x)$, then the limit function will be
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, &x=0 \\ 0, &x >0 \end{cases}$$
But there is a theorem saying that "unform limit of continuous functions is continuous", so this convergence cannot be uniform.

Comment: Thank you for the detail answer. It is helpful for understanding the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Another characterization which will help you a lot...let $M_n=\sup_x|f_n(x)-f(x)|$. Then $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on the given set if   $M_n\rightarrow 0$. In your question $M_n=1$ ..:)